# MySQL 5.7 create Function with int input syntax errors

Tags: mysql, function, mysql-5.7

Trying to create a function in MySQL 5.7 that will return the total sales for a year, formatted with a $, and two decimal places given the year as an integer input.

Table columns InvoiceID, deptid, salsamt, salesdate

```
    DELIMITER $$
    CREATE FUNCTION `tot_sale` (Year INT)
    RETURNS VARCHAR2
    BEGIN
    Select concat('$', format(salesamt), 2)
    from sales
    where YEAR(salesdate) = Year;
    RETURN 1;
    END$$
    DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Also a select statement can return multiple rows and multiple column, which is not supported in `function`. You can use `procedure` for that.

Comment: `format` function accepts two parameter and you have passed only one. it also does not uses the input parameter `year` anywhere. If you can let us know what you want to achieve, we might help.

Answer (score 0):

`2` needs to be the second argument to `FORMAT()`, not an argument to `CONCAT()`.

If a function uses `SELECT`, it has to store the result in a variable. Only procedures are allowed to return a result set directly.

You need to use `SUM(salesamt)` to get the total sales for the year.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION `tot_sale` (Year INT)
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
BEGIN
    DECLARE total VARCHAR(255);
    Select concat('$', format(SUM(salesamt), 2))
    INTO total
    from sales
    where YEAR(salesdate) = Year;
    RETURN @total;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```